# What is inline classes in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

Inline classes: [Inline classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-classes.html)

I want to know what is the exact difference between inline from other classes in kotlin? And I want to know what is exact inline class do and when we will use it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Inline classes are just some kind of typed wrappers over primitive types and strings.

For example, imagine we have an interface declaration like this:

```
interface ResizeableView {
    fun resize(width: Int, height: Int)
}
```

Every time a developer needs to invoke this method he needs to check the parameters order first to not confuse width and height.

And still, what happens if parameters will eventually get messed up?

```
val width: Int = someObject.width
val height: Int = someObject.height
resizeableView.resize(height, width) //compiles ok and brings a bug to the program
```

This example is plain and simple, but for some other case when a method declares a bunch of primitive-typed parameters that conform to a single type, the unwanted behavior of the program can be not so easily understood and so arguments confusion detected.

Inline classes help with this:

```
inline class Width(val value: Int)
inline class Height(val value: Int)

interface ResizeableView {
    fun resize(width: Width, height: Height)
}
```

Because `Width` and `Height` are now different **types**, the confusion is banished when invoking the method.

```
val width: Width = someObject.width
val height: Height = someObject.height
resizeableView.resize(height, width) //compile-time error
```

But what is the point of the `inline` modifier here? Why just don't use `class Width`?
The key thing is that `inline classes` introduce a type only at compile type, and in runtime these variables will be just `int`-s, so no runtime overhead will be created.

[Here](https://jakewharton.com/inline-classes-make-great-database-ids/) is a nice real world example of inline classes application.

Comment: What a good sample! thanks

Comment: While the solution is good, it should be noted that inline classes support functions and inheritance. But it isn't clear how those features are of any real value if you just go with your simplified sample.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add more details besides [@Andrey Ilyunin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7884542/andrey-ilyunin)'s answer.

Inline classes are replaced with underlying values in compiled code that makes it more performant. But why?

Values are stored either on the Stack or the Heap in JVM. For a regular object that is Heap, but allocations and memory fetches on the Heap are slower than Stack. By replacing a class with its underlying value, JVM will be able to store it on the Stack, thus inline classes are faster than regular classes.

**But it's not always true.**

The compiler is not smart enough to replace every inline class with their underlying value.

> inline class is boxed when it is used as another type. Unboxed inline class is used when value is statically known to be inline class.

You should read more in [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/inline-classes.md#java-interoperability) to understand when an inline class can be represented by its underlying value. Inline classes are only getting faster when the value is actually inlined in the compiled code.

Answer (score 0):

Inline classes provide us with a way to wrap a type, thus adding functionality and creating a new type by itself.

As opposed to regular (non-inlined) wrappers, they will benefit from improved performance. This happens because the data is inlined into its usages, and object instantiation is skipped in the resulting compiled code.

You can see a good example on [this](https://medium.com/@anvith/working-with-kotlin-inline-class-daac9822596f)